# Error HQL Query on LIKE

Tags: hibernate

Here is the function and query

```
public List<T> searchWordRecords(String parameter, String paramValue, Long statusID) throws AmmachiServerException
    {
        Session session  = null;
        List<T> recordList = null;

        try
        {
            session = HibernateUtils.getHibernateConnection();
            String hqlQueryString = "Select p from " + theClass.getSimpleName() + " p where " + parameter +" like '% :paramValue%'and StatusID = :statusID";


            Query hqlQuery = session.createQuery(hqlQueryString); 
            hqlQuery.setParameter("paramValue", paramValue);
            hqlQuery.setParameter("statusID", statusID);
            recordList = hqlQuery.list();
        }
        catch(HibernateException he)
        {
            processException(he);
        }
        finally
        {
            HibernateUtils.closeConnection(session);
        }

        return recordList;
    }
```

I got the error org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [paramValue]

Could you please help anyone to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your parameter the other way round - passing the wildcards with it:

```
hqlQuery.setParameter("paramValue", "%" + paramValue + "%");
```

Of course you would have to remove the wildcards from your current query:

```
where parameter like :paramValue
```

Comment: String hqlQueryString = "Select p from " + theClass.getSimpleName() + " p where " + parameter + " = :paramValue and StatusID = :statusID";hqlQuery.setParameter("paramValue", "%" + paramValue + "%");          Is this ok

Comment: You still need the matching, so keep using `like` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to search for `where foo like '%BAR%'`, instead of making the query `where foo like '%:bar%'` and set `:bar` as `"BAR"`, you should have your query as `where foo like :bar` and set `:bar` as `"%BAR%"`

For your example, you should:

```
String hqlQueryString = "Select p from " + theClass.getSimpleName() 
                             + " p where " + parameter +" like :paramValue " 
                             + " and StatusID = :statusID";
//....
hqlQuery.setParameter("paramValue", "%" + paramValue + "%");
//....
```

Just a side-note.  It is normally not recommended to do a `like` and match with `%value%` as having wildcard for the start of string is going to make most, if not all, indices useless.